# php error reporting for single page?

Tags: php, error-handling

Is it possible (and if so, how) to turn on php error reporting to the screen for just one page? I currently have all error reporting to the screen switched off in php ini.

Or another way of asking - if I use error_reporting(E_ALL) on a single page, will it also display errors on other pages (what I don't want)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `error_reporting(E_ALL)` will enable error reporting for only that page!

To display errors use, `ini_set("display_errors", 1)`

Comment: Thanks guys. I know you're all right, because I remember using error_reporting(E_ALL) in the past, but the errors still aren't showing (but they are logging to error_log files, which they have always done). Will error_reporting() override (for that page) any settings I may have set in config files on the server?

Comment: Error_reporting works only for that file and does not change the server settings!

Answer (score 4):

If you call `error_reporting()` within a PHP script, it will only affect that script's runtime (i.e. anything it executes after that call, including other scripts which have been included). It won't modify server configuration etc.

However, it's worth noting that if the script encounters an error before it can make that call, it won't have any effect (i.e. error reporting behaviour will be unchanged). That can be a particular problem if you have a syntax error or similar.

EDIT: It occurs to me that you may want to leave error reporting enabled in your configuration, but only enable `display_errors` as needed. That way you can still get errors written to a log file, but they'll only appear on-screen when you want.

Comment: Thanks Peter - I've set up log file writing for all pages, and only display errors on pages I need now like you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Call `error_reporting(0)` at the beginning of a script to do this. It will block all runtime errors. However, it isn't recommended to do this, except possibly in production code.

[Read more about error_reporting() here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)