# My Login system PHP is not working and logging in

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so first things first here is my code

Login.php

```js
<?php session_start();

//Begin the session here and if the users login is successful a varaible for this session 
//is assigned $_SESSION['id']=ID which will dictate in admin php if they are logged in

?>
<?php
include 'Includes/connect.php';
//if the user submits a username and pass from the loginform pass the 
//data to the variables $username and $password
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

//Pull the data from the login table on the database. Here it is specifiying the sql statement to be used in prepare()
//
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :username";
 $query = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
 $query -> bindParam(':username',$username);
 $query ->execute();
 //store retrieved row to a variable
 $results = $query -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 

 //check to see if we get a result and return the the number of rows affected by the SQL statment and if it is more then 0
 if($results != FALSE && $query -> rowcount() > 0 ) {
  
  //This sets the salt for cyrpting to be the username that is entered and logged in with from loginform.php. This ensures the password on my
  // database is different to that on another one
  $salt =$results['Email'];
  $auth_user = hash('sha256', $salt.$password);
  //This will then hash the password of the admin user that has successfuly logged in
  if($results['password'] == $auth_user ){
  $_SESSION['id']=$results['id'];
  header("Location:user.php");
  exit;
  //if the users inputted password matches that of the one in the login table 
  // set the $_SESSION variable $_SESSION['id'] and redirect to the admin page.

  } 
   else {
   header("Location:loginform.php");
   exit;
   //If login failed direct back to the loginform

 
 }
}else {
  header("Location:loginfssom.php");
  exit;
 }
 //return to loginform.php if failed login
}
?>
```

And basically it is not logging into the site. I probably done something stupid. 2am here and fueled on coffee. Anyway I apologize in advance if its my own ignorance.

login form code

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/user.css" media ="screen">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobile.css" media ="handheld">



</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<header></header>


<body>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="grad"></div>
  <div class="header">
   <div>The<span>  Store</span></div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="login">
   <form action ="login.php" method = "POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required><br>
    <input type ="submit" name = "submit" value="login">
    <li><a href='resetform.php'>Forgot Password</a></li>
    <li><a href='index.php'>Return</a></li>

   </form>
    
  </div>



</body>

</html>





</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does exactly happen? Do you receive any errors? Does it not redirect properly?

Comment: @Andrew It redirects to loginform.php

Comment: Does the username/password combination exist in the database? Drop the header and start debugging. Go line by line and see where it fails. var_dumping stuff is ok, don't be afraid to use it.

Comment: did you try echoing the `$result`? Check if the data in their fit your code.

Comment: Add the HTML markup for your login form to the question.

Comment: Go through your code, using `var_dump('here');` to find where abouts it breaks, and then `var_dump` different values and make sure they are the values that are expected

Comment: check the `if($results['password'] == $auth_user )` and use print for each variable. perhaps those not match.

Comment: I look at your code and raise a small question - is the URL meant to have a capital letter? URLs are case sensitive on Linux (but I think not on Windows based systems?), `include 'Includes/connect.php';` ?

Answer (score 4):

Some points for finding the errors:

1) Do you have your error.log file set up? Do you have PHP recording all errors and warnings?

View this article: [php error reporting for single page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849550/php-error-reporting-for-single-page)

2) Check links to URLs are correct and case sensitively correct, such as `include 'Includes/connect.php';`

ALSO: Some of your column names are all lower case and some are lower and upper such as `$results['Email']` and `$results['password']`. Consistency is suggested, is there a almost-typo here?

3) Check your database contains the correct details you are trying to log in with.

4) Check your hashing method:

For example double check the character encoding in the database as well as the character encoding on the input form as well as trimming and tidying the password field as well.

I would suggest using PHP `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` functions to check the password rather than your own hashing methods.

5) Add `var_dump()` and output your data along with a `die()` statement after each section to check variable values. You can also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php `get_defined_vars` if your page doesn't have a lot going on. This can be very useful.

One or more of the above should solve your problem.