# PHP is preventing the rest of my page from loading properly

Tags: php

I am coding a book store for a school project. We started last semester with html. This semester we are converting it to php for dynamic reasons. I modularized the code the best I can, but when I put the functional section of php in, it prevents all the following html in the php code from displaying. As far as I can tell, I have done everything correctly and can not find the issue.

This is the php call in my index.php

```
<aside class="lSideMenu">
    <table>
        <tr><td><h3>Categories</h3></td></tr>
        <?php
            include_once 'getGenres.php';
            popGenres();
        ?>
        <tr><td><a href="humorbook.html">Humor</a></td></tr>
    </table>
</aside>
```

I left the table row after the call for testing and does not show, but when I look at the debug window the table and aside close tags are there. there is other code after that that does not populate as well and my css breaks.

This is the php funtions of getGenres.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: PoeDawg
 * Date: 4/5/2017
 * Time: 2:51 PM
 */
function db_connect(){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $uname = 'root';
    $pass = 'root';


    $link = new mysqli($host, $uname, $pass);

    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }
    return $link;
}

function popGenres(){

    $link = db_connect();
    $dbname = 'volga_db';

    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($link, $dbname);
    if (!$db_selected) {
        die('Could not connect to database: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM tblgenres';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if ( $result ) {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            echo "<tr><td><a href=\"booklist.html\">" . $row['genreName'] . "</a></td></tr>";
        }

        $result->close();
    }

    mysqli_close()($link);
}
```

It does what it is supposed to in that it populates the list of genres, it just prevents the content below the function call from loading in the browser. If i take the php call section out, the page works as it should. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"it just breaks the rest of my page"* is not quite a helpful description of what is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples) in order to get an (useful) answer.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(' in your code on line 38 mysqli_close()($link);` Please set `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Check your error logs, or [turn on error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850380/1941241) so you can see what is happening. I'm pretty sure you're getting a fatal error (syntax error) on the line with `mysqli_close()($link);`

Comment: I have error reporting turned on through my mysql.ini, but no errors are reported.

Comment: I added the error_reporting(E_ALL); just to be sure and am getting an error now. I removed the extra set of parenthesis and works fine now. I am surprised that the setting of error repoting in the mysql.ini file is not working. Thank you @rickdenhaan , I cant beleive I missed such a simple syntax error.

Comment: @Poedawg While the error is on a line including mysql, it's a PHP syntax error, not a MySQL error

Comment: That makes sense, thank you @ChrisForrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last line of code should be like below,

```
 mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Thank you to both you and @rickdenhaan for pointing me to such a simple syntax error that I was over looking.